# Toggle off when somewhere else is clicked

Tags: jquery, toggle, slidetoggle

I have a ul with important actions that I dont want easily accessable. The ul is hidden with jquery then when the link is clicked it is toggled showing the options. I want the user to be able to click the options but if he/she clicks elsewhere on the page while the ul is still toggled then it is toggled and hidden again

```
<a href="#" id="property-option-handle">Options</a>

<ul id="property-options">
    <li><a href="#">Delete Property</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Archive Property</a></li>
</ul>

$('#property-options').hide();
$("#property-option-handle").click(function() {
    $('#property-options').slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Here is my jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TEBeM/

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/BRBmU/1/

Comment: That works great thanks. How does the e.stopPropagation() work?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#property-options').hide();
    $("#property-option-handle").click(function(evt) {
    $('#property-options').slideToggle("slow");
    evt.stopPropagation();
});

$("#property-options").click(function(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).click(function(evt){
    $('#property-options').slideUp("slow");
    evt.stopPropagation();
});
```

Try this.. It will definitely work.

Comment: Works but still toggles the ul away when i click the ul li. Is there are way to stop this?